# How to fix or remove a stuck cone shape airbrush nozzle

Tags: maintenance, airbrush

The issue happened to many airbrushes using cone shaped nozzles: badger 175.

I tried putting it into fire and the freezer, but none of those methods worked.

[image]

Comment: Its not stated clearly in the question, the nozzle cone is stuck in the cap? If this is happening a lot you are over torquing the cap when assembling.

Answer (score 4):

The Taiwanese factory sent me an email to help me fix an airbrush having the nozzle stuck in the head cap 15 years ago.

The solution is to use a needle-nosed plier:

1. Place the needle-nosed plier's left tip on the left edge, and the right tip of the needle-nosed plier into the nozzle's hole. Grip using little force.
2. Place the needle-nosed plier's right tip on the right edge, the left tip of the needle-nosed plier into the nozzle's hole, grip it using little force.
3. The nozzle falls off!

   [image]

Comment: the tool in the images looks like needle-nosed pliers, not a clamp

Comment: Be careful when using this method. If the pliers/clamp has angled jaws you are likely to damage the nozzle cone which can lead to an uneven spray pattern.

Comment: P.S. Its okay to accept your own answer.